# Curses for PHP on Windows

Tags: php, windows, command-line, ncurses, pdcurses

Is there a Windows equivalent of ncurses for PHP?

I've created a CLI script and want to display various statistics (currently processed record, completion percentage etc.) in a nice way, without outputting loads and heaps of text to the cmd.exe window.

The ncurses extension doesn't work on Windows.

Comment: Looks like our best bet is pdcurses, once someone decides that it would be a good idea to make a PHP module for it.

Comment: I think you're right. I'll leave this question open until then.

Comment: In the last couple of years, Microsoft has added nearly complete, modern support for VT100 XTerm escape sequences to the Windows 10 console (it's not a flawless implementation but it's passable).  I built a simple PHP class that emits a wide variety of XTerm-compatible sequences that seems to work fine on Windows 10:  https://github.com/cubiclesoft/php-misc/blob/master/support/xterm.php  It's not ncurses, but it can be used to output those statistics in your CLI script you were wanting a decade ago.

Comment: @CubicleSoft Thanks, now I feel I need to write an ETL program again 

Answer (score 3):

ncurses only works for unix-like environments so you can use cygwin but [Link outdated] looks promising. Check it out and let me know!

(Edit Apr 2016: removed the link as it's out of date and clicking on it takes you down a nasty path.)

Comment: Thanks. I know about Cygwin, but I'm trying to do this with the native Windows console. It doesn't have to be ncurses, just an equivalent solution for Windows.

Answer (score 2):

There is [pdcurses](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/index.html) which I believe works in a windows console window.  The aren't any PHP bindings so you would need to build your own.

Comment: I don't have enough knowledge of C or the PHP core to be able to do that.